# Body Height pushing down footer too far

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble with my body extending my footer too far.

My CSS:

```
body{
    background-color:#EDEDED !important;
    background-image:url('http://static.lukepolo.com/public/assets/img/broken_noise.png') !important;
}

body > .container{
    min-height:100%;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
 }

footer{
    padding:10px;
    background-image:url('http://static.lukepolo.com/public/assets/img/broken_noise.png') !important;
    color:white;
}
footer p{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">

</div>
<footer>
        <?php echo $footer;?>
</footer>
```

Here is my link: 
http://lukepolo.com/blog

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly common css problem, and as so there's a typical solution.

You need to pull the footer up by adding a negative `margin-top` to it, that's equal to it's height. Then to ensure that it doesn't overlap any of the content inside .container, add, this time to .container, a `padding-bottom` that's also equal to the footer's height (equal or higher).

Comment: @user1212047 Using the same idea, absolute positioning may be better than a negative `margin-top`.

Comment: to use position: absolute you'd had to put the footer inside a div containing both footer and, as user1212047, called it .container. you'd also have to specify the width on the footer because of what position: absolute does. I think margin-top is simpler, and better for this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the scrollbar appears because you add padding to the footer.

I you're trying to achieve sticky footer, then this might help you: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the:

```
body > .container{
    min-height:100%;
}
```

since that is what is causing the footer to be off the screen.